# Fill factor SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does Fill factor in SQL Server matter while deleting record  from table?
If yes what should be the consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill Factor comes into play only when Index is rebuilt/Created. During normal insert /delete/updates ,this is not honored

See this answer as well ,for more details:[Difference in number of logical reads for similar set of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414180/difference-in-number-of-logical-reads-for-similar-set-of-data/38414674#38414674)