# Difference in number of logical reads for similar set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following code:

```
create table t(i int,j char(3000))
create table t1(i int,j char(3000))

create unique clustered index ixt on t(i) with (FILLFACTOR=20)

declare @n int = 0
while @n < 1000
begin
  insert into t values(@n*2,'a')
  insert into t1 values(@n*2,'a')
  set @n = @n+1
end

create unique clustered index ixt1 on t1(i) with (FILLFACTOR=20)
```

Both of the above tables have same structure,data types and even same data,but querying them gives me different logical reads..

```
select * from t where i between 100 and 150 --returns 16 logical reads
select * from t1 where i between 100 and 150 --returns 30 logical reads
```

Can anyone please tell me why query in `table t1` returns more logical reads than the query from `table t` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the way you are creating an index (creating first ,for one table and last, for one table )  and With varying Fill factor settings..

Fill Factor as we know , determines how much free space is left in leaf level page of index,in this case you are asking to set it 20 which means, leave the rest of 80% free..

**Emphasis needed:**
 **[Fill factor setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952717/fill-factor-sql-server/36952898#36952898) will be honored only when index is rebuilt or created**.

**First Case:**
Even though you create an index with fill factor of 20,there is no data,so free space is not left  and we know while inserting this setting is not honored.

Querying table1 pages show there are only 500 rows

```
 select object_name(object_id),index_depth,index_level,avg_fragmentation_in_percent,avg_page_space_used_in_percent,page_count  from 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),0,-1,0,'Detailed')
where object_id=object_id('t')
```

[image]

**Second case:**
You are creating an index after data is inserted and SQL will honor the setting,pages will be rearranged to honor this setting..

Table2 page count gives us 1000 rows..

```
select object_name(object_id),index_depth,index_level,avg_fragmentation_in_percent,avg_page_space_used_in_percent,page_count  from 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),0,-1,0,'Detailed')
where object_id=object_id('t1')
```

[image]

Even though table count is same,number of pages are different due to the way you are creating index.This is the reason why you are seeing different logical reads for each table with same data and structure

If you query after rebuilding both indexes ,you will see same logical reads